# What is the fastest way to remove a directory tree in windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am trying to remove a directory recursively. I don't care about whether the files go into the Recycle Bin.

When I open a command prompt and and enter `rmdir C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\atmp /s`, it takes a long time to remove the directory and I have to wait for it to finish before I get the prompt.

Is there a better way to remove a directory recursively?

Comment: `cd` into the containing directory, execute `explorer .` and move that folder to the recycle bin. Alternatively press Delete or Shift+Delete for permanent deletion (no recycle bin).

Answer (score 1):

Use a *quiet mode* if prompt is an issue:

```
rmdir /s /q C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\atmp
```